# Does the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left(2^{1/n} - 1\right)\,$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, exponential-function

I'm trying to determine if the following sum converges or diverges (this is question 38 in section 11.7 of Stewart's Early Transcendentals):

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}(2^{1/n} - 1)$$

I've considered all of the techniques I know (integration test, ratio test, etc.), but I upon inspection, none of them will solve this problem.

Any hints or help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that $(2^x)'_{x=0}=\log 2$, SO $2^{1/n}-1=\log 2\cdot n^{-1}+O(n^2) $

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Strictly speaking, I think the antecedent by itself only implies that $2^{1/n} - 1 = \log 2 \cdot n^{-1} + o(n^{-1})$ (unless one takes advantage of analyticity or higher-order derivatives).

Comment: @ErickWong Sure.

Comment: @Pedro: "Sure" means "Yeah, you're right, but who cares?" Is this the message you intended?

Comment: @TonyK Absolutely not. I was just asserting Erick is right on his observation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the [Mean Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)
$$
\mathrm{e}^h-1=h\,\mathrm{e}^{\vartheta h},
$$
for some $\vartheta\in(0,1)$.

In our case
$$
2^{1/n}-1=\mathrm{e}^{\ln 2/n}-1=\frac{\ln 2}{n}\mathrm{e}^{\vartheta \ln 2/n}>\frac{\ln 2}{n},
$$
since $\vartheta\in(0,1)$.

Hence the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \big(2^{1/n}-1\big),
$$
diverges to infinity, by virtue of the *Comparison Test*, since so does series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log 2}{n}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

You may try to use Limit Comparison Test with $1/n$.

**Edit:**

Note that $2^{1/n}=e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln2}=1+\frac{1}{n}\ln2+\frac{(\frac{1}{n}\ln2)^2}{2!}+\frac{(\frac{1}{n}\ln2)^3}{3!}+\ldots$.

With this note, it is natural to think of the above mentioned test.

Comment: Could you possibly expand on that a bit more? Why $1/n$?

Comment: @Sim What is the derivative of $2^x$ at $x=0$? What is $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{1/n}-1}{1/n}$$

Comment: @Sim I edited my answer, hope that it will help.

Answer (score 3):

The function $x \mapsto 2^x - 1$ is strictly increasing and strictly convex; in particular, it lies above its tangent line at $0$ for all $x > 0$. Letting $f$ be the first order linear approximation from the tangent line, we have

$$f(x) = (2^0 - 1) + \ln 2 \left(x - 0\right) = x \ln 2$$

Therefore,

$$2^{1/n} - 1 > f\left(\frac 1 n \right) = \frac{\ln 2}{n}$$

Thus, by comparison to the harmonic series, the series is divergent.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting that you can get a useful comparison without making use of calculus.

Let $2^{1/n}-1=a_n$.  It's clear that $a_n\gt0$ for all $n$.  Therefore, from

$$2=(1+a_n)^n=1+na_n+{n\choose2}a_n^2+\cdots+{n\choose n}a_n^n$$

we get

$$a_n={1\over n}\left(1-{n\choose2}a_n^2-\cdots-{n\choose n}a_n^n \right)\lt{1\over n}$$

But $a_n\lt1/n$ now implies

$$\begin{align}
{n\choose2}a_n^2+{n\choose3}a_n^3+\cdots+{n\choose n}a_n^n
&\lt{n(n-1)\over2!n^2}+{n(n-1)(n-2)\over3!n^3}+\cdots+{n(n-1)\cdots2\cdot1\over n!n^n}\\
&\le{1\over2!}+{1\over3!}+\cdots+{1\over n!}\\
&\lt{1\over2}+{1\over6}\left(1+{1\over2}+{1\over4}+{1\over8}+\cdots \right)\\
&={5\over6}
\end{align}$$

(Note, we could have gotten $e-2$ instead of $5/6$, but I'm trying to avoid anything that smacks of calculus, and all we really need is a bound less than $1$.)

Putting this back into the expression for $a_n$ gives

$$a_n={1\over n}\left(1-{n\choose2}a_n^2-\cdots-{n\choose n}a_n^n \right)\gt{1\over n}\left(1-{5\over6} \right)={1\over6n}$$

and that's all we need.

Comment: A really nice answer =)

Answer (score 3):

You can approach this problem with a simple inequality: if $a>b>0$, then:
$$ n(a-b)\,b^{n-1}<a^n-b^n < n(a-b)\,a^{n-1},\tag{1}$$
so, if we choose $a=2^{1/n}$ and $b=1$, from the $RHS$ we get:
$$ 2^{1/n}-1 > \frac{1}{n\cdot 2^{\frac{n-1}{n}}}>\frac{1}{2n}\tag{2}$$
so the series diverges by comparison with the harmonic series.